# How to correct the position of ng-multiselect-dropdown's selection number?

Tags: html, css, angular, drop-down-menu

How can I avoid the overlap between the number and the dropdown caret in ng-multiselect-dropdown?

[image]

I tired finding the element to style it. But I am not able to add styling to this.

[image]

Comment: Can you not just find an appropriate selector for the element holding the number and add margin-right: 1vw ?

Comment: If you add some code, I can help you.

Comment: @Alex I tried that. But it's showing `element.style {
    padding-right: 6px;
}` .  I tried styling this. But didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
:host ::ng-deep .multiselect-dropdown .dropdown-btn {     
  padding: 6px 24px 6px 12px !important;      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.multiselect-dropdown .dropdown-btn {
padding :6px 12px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
:host ::ng-deep .multiselect-dropdown .dropdown-btn .selected-item {
  width: 90%;
}
```